# Obtendo dados entre 3 tabelas no yii , cgridview

Tags: yii

Estou a utilizar o framework yii e preciso das informações que estão na tabela rota.
Estou buscando essas informações a partir da tabela veiculo.
Existe uma terceira tabela chamada equipamento
Em veiculo tenho uma chave estrangeira chamada equipamento_fk
Em rota tenho uma chave estrangeira para equipamento (equipamento_fk)
Relation de veiculo:

```
'cliente' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Cliente', 'Cliente'),
'equipamento0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Equipamento', 'equipamento'),
'motorista0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Motorista', 'motorista'),
```

A duvida é como a partir de veiculo posso obter os dados que estão na tabela rota. E usar estas informações com o cgridview.

[image: Exemplo / duvida relation com 3 tabelas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer colocar no `CGridView` informações de uma tabela terceira. Pelo que pude notar você tem uma relação `N to N` entre `Veículos` e `Rotas`.

Segundo a referencia(em inglês) da wiki do Framework você terá que:

1º) No model de Veículo deverá adicionar uma variável:

```
public $rotas_search;
```

2º) Alterar a função `rules()` para adicionar o novo campo na lista de "Safe on Search".

```
  public function rules() {
    return array(
      ...
      array( '........,rotas_search', 'safe', 'on'=>'search' ),
    );
  }
```

3º) Agora é necessário adicionar o campo no seu método `search()`

```
public function search() {
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->with = array( 'equipamento0' );
  ...
  //Onde rotas é a relação entre a tabela equipamento e a tabela rota
  //rotas[0] indica que vai pegar a primeira rota da lista.
  $criteria->compare( 'equipamento0.rotas[0].id', $this->rotas_search, true );
  ...
}
```

4º) Então, no final do método `search` você modifica o retorno, adicionando seu novo campo.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider( $this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'rotas_search'=>array(
                'asc'=>'equipamento0.rotas[0].id',
                'desc'=>'equipamento0.rotas[0].id DESC',
            ),
            '*',
        ),
    ),
));
```

5º) Por fim no seu `CGridView`, adicione a coluna.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
...
    'columns'=>array(
        array( 'name'=>'rotas_search', 'value'=>'$data->equipamento0->rotas[0]->id' ),
...
    ),
));
```

Perceba que só funciona para a exibição de um valor das rotas. Você pode encontrar mais informações e outras abordagens deste problema [aqui](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/385/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-hasmany-manymany-relations-in-cgridview/)(inglês). E [aqui](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23763-how-to-cgridview-with-has-many-or-many-many-relation/)(inglês) você terá outra abordagem de como colocar mais de um campo na exibição(eu achei um tanto gambiarra, mas se funciona e não trás problemas, então é uma solução).

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$equipamentos = $model->Equipamento;

foreach($equipamentos as $equipamento) {
    echo 'codigo_equipamento:'.$equipamento->id.'<br/>';
    echo '<hr />';

}
```

assim podendo fazer para outras tabelas relacionadas.

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta. Eu preciso fazer de forma a adicionar  o que eu obter da tabela rota no criteria(with) para enviar e utilizar com o cgridview. algo como $data->rota->campo_desejado.

Comment: voce tendo o model carregado com as fks corretas ... voce consegue pegar estes outros dados entendeu